# How to get value only from json array using Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to get the value only from a json array. I have search some answer in stackoverflow but seems like not the one for me.

**my code looks like this:**

```
.done(function (data) {
     var jdata = JSON.stringify(data['queryBuilder']);
     var arrdata = JSON.parse(jdata);
     var fdata = JSON.stringify(arrdata);
     printtopdf(fdata);
);


//this code is from the answer posted here in stackoverflow:
function printtopdf(fdata) {
     var values = Object.keys(fdata).map(function (key) { return fdata[key]; });
     console.log(fdata);
}
```

**and the result:**

```
[
 {
  "rownum":2,
  "rr_id":"RR2100001",
  "ref_id":"UCL2100001",
  "cdescription":"65UGHDFH56Y</br>, 65UGHDFH56Y</br>",
  "rr_status":"Pending",
  "date_created":"2021-01-08 13:46:03"
 }
]
```

**I just want to get the value only, like this:**

```
[
 2,
 "RR2100001",
 "UCL2100001",
 "65UGHDFH56Y</br>, 65UGHDFH56Y</br>",
 "Pending",
 "2021-01-08 13:46:03"
]
```

Any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `Array.prototype.map` and `Object.prototype.values`.

```js
const data = [
 {
  "rownum":2,
  "rr_id":"RR2100001",
  "ref_id":"UCL2100001",
  "cdescription":"65UGHDFH56Y</br>, 65UGHDFH56Y</br>",
  "rr_status":"Pending",
  "date_created":"2021-01-08 13:46:03"
 }
];

// Get values for all data points
const v1 = data.map(value => Object.values(value));
console.log(v1);

// Get values for first data point
const v2 = Object.values(data.shift());
console.log(v2);
```

Comment: const data = fdata; const values = data.map(value => Object.values(value)); console.log(values); returns: data.map is not a function

Comment: You would use `const data = arrdata`. `fdata` is a string, not an array, based on the code you posted.